# activerecord create_table like existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, connection, create-table

With Rails/ActiveRecord 2.3.8 I'd like to do:

```
AnyModel.connection.create_table( 'temp_any_model', temporary: true, id: false, options: 'like any_model' )
```

But AR insists on adding "()" to the generated SQL even though the field list is blank since the table DDL is being cloned, thus resulting in e.g.:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') like any_model' at line 1: 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_any_model` () like any_model
```

Is there any way to coerce AR to generate this simple `create table`new`like existing` statement?

Besides obviously `connection.execute(string)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The parenthesis are hard coded in `create_table`:

```
def create_table(table_name, options = {})
  # snipped ...

  create_sql = "CREATE#{' TEMPORARY' if options[:temporary]} TABLE "            
  create_sql << "#{quote_table_name(table_name)} ("                             
  create_sql << table_definition.to_sql                                         
  create_sql << ") #{options[:options]}"                                        
  execute create_sql        
end
```

There's nothing wrong with using execute on a string literal; I would do that if you don't feel like writing a quick patch.